# Show Multiple DIVS on Dropdown select change

Tags: jquery

Friends

I have a Dropdown select value 
i.e

```
<div class="controls left-padded-controls">
<form:select id="selectField" class="input-medium" path="">
<option value="option1">Test flow1</option>
<option value="option2">Test flow2</option>
</form:select>    
</div>
```

Now based on the above dropdown option selected , I have

```
<label class="control-label left-padded-control-label"><spring:message code="message.description"></spring:message>:&nbsp; 
</label>
<div id="option1" class="box">Content 1</div>
<div id="option2" class="box">Content 2</div>
<br/>
```

And

```
<label class="control-label left-padded-control-label"><spring:message code="message.dynamic.audio.files"></spring:message>:&nbsp;              </label>
<div id="option3" class="box">Content 3</div>
<div id="option4" class="box">Content 4</div>
```

**Now based on the Dropdown Option i.e testflow 1
I want to display div id "option1" and "option3"
and on selection of testflow2 , I want to display div id="option2" and "option4"**

To achieve above My JQuery code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
     $('#option2').show();
    $('#selectField').change(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

But it is Not working as expected , Please suggest the suitable changes,

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#option2').show();
    $('#selectField').change(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        var option = $(this).val();
        $('#'+option).show();
        $('#'+(option=="option1" ? "option3" : "option4")).show();
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4H2Z/)